# mount a directory from docker container to the linux ubuntu host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount

I would like to mount a directory from inside a docker to my linux Ubuntu host machine using `docker-compose.yml`.

The directory in the docker container is `/usr/local/XXX` and I want to mount it on `/home/Projects/XX`

How can I make it happen?

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  MyContainer:
    image: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/XXX/MyContainer:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: MyContainer
    hostname: MyContainer_docker
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "XXXX:XX"
    volumes:
      - /home/Project/workspace/XXX/XXXX:/home/XX
    environment:
      - ...
    extra_hosts:
      - ...
    networks:
      net_plain3:
        ipv4_address: ...

networks:
  # ...etc...
```

Comment: That's not possible. You mount from the host into the container.

Comment: Search for `docker bind mount` in your favorite search engine. As explained by @super above, this is done the other way around, i.e you mount a host folder into the container and not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the right driver options.

Technically, you still mount the host directory to the container, but the result is that the host directory is populated with the data in the container directory. Usually it's the other way around. That's why you need those driver options.

```yaml
services:
  somebox:
    volumes:
      - xx-vol:/usr/local/XXX

volumes:
  xx-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/Projects/XX
```

> Empty named volumes are initialized with the content of the image at the mount location when the container is created.
> - bmitch

So the key here is to create a named volume that uses as device the desired location on the host.

---

As a full working demonstration.

I create the following Dockerfile to add text file in the /workspace dir:

```
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /workspace
RUN echo "Hello World" > hello.txt
```

Then a compose.yaml to build this image and mount a volume with these driver options:

```yaml
services:
  databox:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - data:/workspace

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/blue/scrap/vol/data
```

Now I run the below commands:

```sh
$ mkdir data

$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container vol-databox-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
Attaching to vol-databox-1
vol-databox-1 exited with code 0

$ cat /home/blue/scrap/vol/data/hello.txt
Hello World
```

As you can see, the hello.txt file ended up on the host. It was not created after container startup but was already inside the container's file system when the container started, since it has been added during build.

That means, it is possible to populate a host directory with data from a container in such a way that the data doesn't have to be generated after volume mount, which is usually the case.